# You attempted to initiate an outbound phone call to a phone number that is not enabled on your account

Tags: twilio, twilio-api, twilio-php, twilio-twiml

I have implemented twilio client calling future using PHP. But sometimes the call is getting disconnected after ringing. When I look into the error log in twilio I can see the message 'You attempted to initiate an outbound phone call to a phone number that is not enabled on your account.'. I am calling from browser to browser and browser to mobile app, so why this message is shown ?.

I am not sure whether this is an issue in caller side or the receiver side.

Twiml code
For eg : $to = 'CLIENT3150'

```
function get_voice_response($to,$from,$name,$image, $group) {
     $response = new VoiceResponse();

     if (!empty($to) && strlen($to) > 0) {
        $number = htmlspecialchars($to);
        $dial = $response->dial('', ['callerId' => $from]);
    
        // wrap the phone number or client name in the appropriate TwiML verb
        // by checking if the number given has only digits and format symbols
        if (preg_match("/^[\d\+\-\(\) ]+$/", $number)) {
           $dial->number($number);
        } else {
           $client = $dial->client($number);
           $client->parameter(['name' => 'FirstName', 'value' => $name]);
           $client->parameter(['name' => 'Image', 'value' => $image]);
           $client->parameter(['name' => 'Group', 'value' => $group]);
        }
     } else {
       $response->say("Thanks for calling!");
     }
     return (string)$response;
 }
```

Thank you

Comment: Both numbers are your twilio numbers?

Comment: I am not calling to a phone number. I am calling from browser to browser and browser to mobile app

Comment: The question says you are not calling from browser to browser.

Comment: Sorry edited now

Comment: Can you share the code you are using in your TwiML app to place the outbound call?

Comment: @philnash Updated the question. Pls have a look

Comment: Are you using the string "CLIENT3150" as the `To` number you are dialling? Can you explain that further?

Comment: Oh, actually I think I know what might be going on, one sec.

Answer (score 0):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

It looks like you are [making a call to another client and trying to pass parameters along with the call](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml/client?code-sample=code-send-custom-parameters-to-client&code-language=PHP&code-sdk-version=5.x). When you do this, you need to pass the client name as an `<Identity>` element within the `<Client>`, along with the `<Parameter>` elements.

In PHP this looks like:

```php
$client = $dial->client();
$client->identity($number);
$client->parameter(['name' => 'FirstName', 'value' => $name]);
$client->parameter(['name' => 'Image', 'value' => $image]);
$client->parameter(['name' => 'Group', 'value' => $group]);
```

Let me know if that helps at all.

Comment: @philansh No nothing has changed. The call is getting diconnected immediatly after I accept the call

Comment: And this is not happening all the time. Sometimes I am able to accept the call and speak

Comment: Are there any differences between the calls you can answer and those you can't? Different clients, calls coming from different places, device on which you are taking the calls, error messages in the developer tools? Anything at all?

Comment: No this happens randomly and I cannot figure it out. It even happens when I call from browser to browser or sometimes from browser to mobile. I couldnt find any error in the twilio dashbord error log

Comment: If it's random then there might be something else going on. I'd try to get some examples of Call SIDs where this happened and submit them with this description to [Twilio support](https://www.twilio.com/help/contact).

Comment: I think this happens when multiple tabs of my web app is opened in the browser.

Comment: could you please have a look at this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67948063/issue-with-recieving-twillio-call